# Why wasn't a search party sent for the Avatar?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

I was recently wondering about how Aang escaped the Southern Air Temple trying to escape his destiny as the Avatar. How come the Air Nomads sent no search teams to find him? After all he was just a 12 year old at the time and more importantly he was the Avatar.

Answer (score 5):

It seems likely that they *did* send out search parties for Aang, starting with the [areas most close to the temple](https://external-preview.redd.it/D6COo3YmmcBYv5zwCHMdZO4kUjpczWZjNc-Td7cHH20.jpg?auto=webp&s=96e43204a9d64cee57ed9b0acda8f2e05106c180). But why wouldn't they have found him?

Time is one reason. The very same year, [Sozin started his war](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/History_of_the_World_of_Avatar), wiping out the Air Nomads.

There's also the fact that the iceberg was a very good hiding spot. Even if the Air Nomads didn't have much time to look for Aang, the Fire Nation did and obviously couldn't find him.

Comment: That was my thinking. The *water nomads* didn't find him for a century despite him being right under their noses. How the heck are the air nomads gonna find him?